# Getting array element from parsed json returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json

So, I have this json string:

```
 {"data": [{"articles": [{"title": "Title 1","desc": "Nullam at massa ante. Quisque tempus lacinia est, vel hendrerit libero. Nunc consequat feugiat nulla et sollicitudin."}]},{"pictures": [{"src": "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"}]}, {"videos": [{"src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7X8II6J-6mU"}]}]}
```

I use this code to parse it:

```
let data = JSON.parse(json);
```

When I log in console this:

```
let articles = data.data[0];
console.log(articles);
```

I get this in console:

```
{articles: Array(1)}articles: Array(1)0: {title: "Title 1", desc: "Nullam at massa ante. Quisque tempus lacinia est, …ro. Nunc consequat feugiat nulla et sollicitudin."}
```

But when I try this (I even tried using get path option from console to get title):

```
console.log(articles[0]);
```

I get undefined.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `articles` variable isn’t an array. It has an `articles` property that is. Try `articles.articles[0]`